# filtered Query for objectContext Using Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, winforms, optimization, linq-to-sql, sql-server-ce

i have tried to search some examples about my approach but all questions was not close enough to what i was trying to achieve .

for the TLDR sake , Question is : **how do i make it work as in plain sql query?**

using c# - Winforms with SqlCompact4 and Linq to SQL

my scenario involves a form with all the relevant Db table columns as availble filters to query

and then on text change event of each filtertextbox as a filter, the datasource of the gridview updates accordingly
and because i allow filtered search via many of them columns i was trying to avoid use of some extra
lines of code.

so lets say we only concentrate on 4 columns

custID, name, email, cellPhone

each has its corresponding TextBox.
i am trying to make a query as follows :

first i systematically collect all Textbox into a List

```
var AllFormsSearchFiltersTBXLst = new List<TextBox>();
```

code that collects all tbx on current form

```
var AllFormsSearchFiltersTBXLst = [currentFormHere].Controls.OfType<TextBox>();
```

so now i have all of textboxes as filters regardless if they have any value 
then check who has some value in it

forech textbox in this filters textboxes if text length is greater than zero

it means that current filter is active

then.. a second list AllFormsACTIVESearchfiltersTBXLst will contain only active filters

what i was trying to achieve was in same way i didn't have to specify each of textbox objects 
i just looped through each of them all as a collection and didn't have to specify each via it's id

now i want to make a filter on a dbContext using only those active filters

so i will not have to ask if current tbxName  is email
like

```
query = db.Where(db=>db.email.Contains(TbxEmail.Text));
```

and again and again for each of 10 to 15 columns

what i have got so far is nothing that implements what i was heading to.

```
 using (SqlCeConnection ClientsConn = new SqlCeConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn_DB_RCL_CRM2014"].ConnectionString))
        {
            System.Data.Linq.Table<ContactsClients> db = null;
            // get all column names from context 
            var x =(System.Reflection.MemberInfo[]) typeof(ContactsClients).GetProperties();

            using (DB_RCL_CRM2014Context Context = new DB_RCL_CRM2014Context(ClientsConn))
            {
                if (!Filtered)
                    db = Context.ContactsClients;//.Where(client => client.Name.Contains("fler"));
                else
                {
                    db = Context.ContactsClients;
                    // filters Dictionary contains the name of textBox and its value 
                    // I've named TBX as Columns names specially so i could equalize it to the columns names when needed to automate 
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string,string> CurFltrKVP in FiltersDict)
                    {
                        foreach (var memberInfo in x)
                        {
                         // couldn't find out how to build the query 
                        }

                    }


                }

                BindingSource BS_Clients = new BindingSource();
                BS_Clients.DataSource = db;
                GV_ClientInfo_Search.DataSource = BS_Clients;
```

what i normally do when working with plain sql is

foreach textbox take its value and add it into a string as filter

var q = "where " ;

```
   foreach(tbx CurTBX in ALLFILTERTBX)
   {
    q +=CurTBX.Name +" LIKE '%"  + CurTBX.Text + "%'";
    // and some checking  of last element in list off cores 
   }
```

then pass this string as a filter to the main select query ... that simple 
how do i make it work as in plain sql query?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you're trying to get the property of `db` dynamically, like: `db.email` according to the looped name of your textbox (here `'email'`). However, I recommend you to do it some other way. I'd make a `switch` for each type of the property, like: `email`, `name` etc. Something like this:

```
// Create a list for the results
var results = new List<YourDBResultTypeHere>();

foreach(tbx CurTBX in ALLFILTERTBX)
{
   switch(CurTBX.Name) {
      case "email":
         results.AddRange(db.Where(db => db.email.Contains(tbx.Text)).ToList());
         break;
      case "name":
         results.AddRange(db.Where(db => db.name.Contains(tbx.Text)).ToList());
         break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    void UpdateGridViewData(bool Filtered=false, Dictionary<string,string> FiltersDict = null)
    {

        using (SqlCeConnection ClientsConn = new SqlCeConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn_DB_RCL_CRM2014"].ConnectionString))
        {
            System.Data.Linq.Table<ContactsClients> db = null;
            IEnumerable<ContactsClients> IDB = null;
            BindingSource BS_Clients = new BindingSource();
            System.Reflection.MemberInfo[] AllDbTblClientsColumns = (System.Reflection.MemberInfo[])typeof(ContactsClients).GetProperties();

            using (DB_RCL_CRM2014Context Context = new DB_RCL_CRM2014Context(ClientsConn))
            {
                if (!Filtered)
                {
                    db = Context.ContactsClients;
                    BS_Clients.DataSource = db;
                }
                else
                {
                    string fltr = "";
                    var and = "";
                    if (FiltersDict.Count > 1) and = "AND";
                    for (int i = 0; i < FiltersDict.Count; i++)
                    {
                        KeyValuePair<string, string> CurFltrKVP = FiltersDict.ElementAt(i);
                        if (i >= FiltersDict.Count-1) and = "";
                        for (int j = 0; j < AllDbTblClientsColumns.Length; j++)
                        {

                            if (AllDbTblClientsColumns[j].Name.Equals(CurFltrKVP.Key))
                            {

                                fltr += string.Format("{0} Like '%{1}%' {2} ", AllDbTblClientsColumns[j].Name, CurFltrKVP.Value, and);


                            }

                        }

                    }
                    try
                    {
                        IDB = Context.ExecuteQuery<ContactsClients>(
                          "SELECT * " +
                          "FROM ContactsCosmeticsClients " +
                          "WHERE " + fltr

                        );
                        BS_Clients.DataSource = IDB;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }

                }



                GV_ClientInfo_Search.DataSource = BS_Clients;

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is "this"? Code-only answers are of little value.

Comment: @GertArnold i am totally not an expert in this field of linq nor dynamic or even linq to object but seems all it was missing is the use of ExecuteQuery<T>() method then the 'plain' sql cmd string and some logic to handle trimming the last AND in last iteration, as for me i would really be more than happy to see another approach mate .

Comment: OK, could be, but it's better to point that out additionally because most of us aren't difference viewers by nature.